# Only Import File when it contains certain numbers from a Table

Tags: matlab, import

I got a couple 100 sensor measurement files all containing the date and time of measurement. All the files have names that include date and time. Example:

```
07-06-2016_17-58-32.wf
07-06-2016_18-02-32.wf
...
...
08-06-2016_17:48-26.wf
```

I have a function (importfile) and a loop that imports my data. The loop looks like this:

```
Files = dir('C:\Osci\User\*.waveform');
numFiles = length(Files);
Data = cell(1, numFiles);

 for fileNum = 1:numFiles
     Data{fileNum} = importfile(Files(fileNum).name);
 end
```

Not all of these waveform files are useful. The measurement files are only useful if they were generated in a certain time period. I got a table that shows my allowed time periods:

```
07-Jun-2016 18:00:01
07-Jun-2016 18:01:31
07-Jun-2016 18:02:01
...
```

I want to modify my loop, so that the files (.waveform files) are only imported if the numbers for **day** (first number), **hour** (4th number) and **minute** (5th number) from the files match the numbers of the table containing the allowed time periods.

EDIT: Rather than a scalar hour, minute, and second, there is a vector of each. In my case, MyDay, MyHour and MyMinute are 1100x1 matrices while fileTimes only consists of 361 rows.

So, using the provided example the loop should only import file

```
07-06-2016_18-02-32.wf
```

since it is the only one where the numbers match (in this case 7, 18, 02).

---

---

EDIT2: Using @erfan's answer (and changing some directories and variable names) I have the following working code:

```
fmtstr = 'O:\\Basic_Research_All\\Lange\\Skripe ISAT\\Rohdaten\\*_%02i-*-*_%02i-%02i-*.wf';
Files = struct([]);

n = size(MyDayMyHourMyMinute);

for N = 1:n;
    Files = [Files; dir(sprintf(fmtstr, MyDayMyHourMyMinute(N,:)))];
end

numFiles = length(Files);
WaveformData = cell(1, numFiles);

 for fileNum = 1:numFiles
     WaveformData{fileNum} = importfile(Files(fileNum).name);
 end
```

Comment: Where do you get the `7, 18, 02` numbers from?

Comment: The numbers are in the title of each file (see the file names in my example, first table).    If you mean the numbers from the time periods, I got a table with all time periods and generate a new table containing only the allowed time periods.    If you mean where do I get the specific numbers 7, 18, 02 from, I just used them in this example.    Does that help?

Comment: Your idea is ok, use an if (there is no loop in ifs) but just the conditions will be more complicated. First you need to check if the next file is allowed, so you need to crosscheck every file to the whole table. There isno msitery, jsut code to write

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I meant if statement. Is the idea of using ~isempty correct? If you could answer that, then I have a key word to search for and look how I have to write the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply your selection from the beginning. Imagine the acceptable values for *day*, *hour* and *minute* are saved in `acc` as an `n*3` matrix. If you replace the first line of your code with:

```
fmtstr = 'C:\Osci\User\%02i-*-*_%02i-%02i-*.wf';
Files = struct([]);
for ii = 1:n
    Files = [Files; dir(sprintf(fmtstr, acc(ii,:)))];
end
```

Then you have already applied your criteria to `Files`. The rest is the same.

Comment: Thank you too! I implemented your code (with some changes in directory and so, which are now necessary). See my EDIT2.  However, the Data Import only works up to a certain file (`Ring6_08-06-2016_01-42-33.wf`). Is there any reason why that happens?

Comment: You are welcome. Are you sure about the value assigned to `n` before your `for` loop? I guess the code will go through all files if you replace `n` with `size(MyDayMyHourMyMinute, 1)`.

Comment: Of course! That's it. Seems like I did not fully understand your code, that's why I assigned n wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

Since your filenames are pretty well defined as dates and times, you can prefilter your list by turning them into actual dates and times:

```
% Get the file list
Files = dir('C:\Osci\User\*.waveform');

% You only need the names
Files = {Files.name};

% Get just the filename w/o the extension
[~, baseFileNames] = cellfun(@(x) fileparts(x), Files, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Your filename is just a date, so parse it as such
fileTimes = datevec(baseFileNames, 'mm-dd-yyyy_HH-MM-SS');

% Now pick out the files you want
% goodFiles = fileTimes(:, 4) == myHour & fileTimes(:, 5) == myMinute & fileTimes(:, 6) == mySecond;
goodFiles = ismember(fileTimes(:, 4:6), [myHour(:), myMinute(:), mySecond(:)], 'rows');

% Pare down your list of filenames
Files = Files(goodFiles);

% Preallocate your data cell
Data = cell(1, numel(Files));

% Now do your loop
for idx = 1:numel(Data)
    Data{idx} = importfile(Files{idx});
end
```

You will, of course, need to define `myHour`, `myMinute` and `mySecond`. Of course, using the logical indexing in goodFiles, you could impose any sort of time criteria, like time or date range. If you find that your filenames aren't so well defined, you could parse out the filename using `textscan` or `strfind` to get the bits you want. The important thing is that cell arrays can be indexed into in much the same way as numerical or string arrays and it's often better to vectorize your filter criteria and then only do the loop on the parts you have to.

---

The OP indicated in a comment below that rather than a scalar hour, minute, and second, there is a vector of each. In that case, use `ismember` to match the two time vectors and return a logical index vector. With 2015a, MathWorks introduced the function `ismembertol`, which allows one to check membership within a certain tolerance.

Comment: `% Now pick out the files you want
goodFiles = fileTimes(:, 4) == myHour & fileTimes(:, 5) == myMinute & fileTimes(:, 6) == mySecond;`

returns an error because the matrix dimensions must agree. In my case, `MyDay`, `MyHour` and `MyMinute` are 1100x1 matrices while fileTimes only consists of 361 rows.

Comment: In your post, you made it sound like your hour, minute, and second were scalars, which is how I tested my code here. I realize you have already accepted an answer, but that detail is very important for anyone else who may come here with a similar problem. You should edit your question to include details about what your time vectors look like.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it  shows a detailed way how to filter the data without using an additional loop, which surely will be useful for future projects. So thanks for the help! I will try to clarify my question.

Comment: @Tierce, I realized you have not accepted this answer yet. Just a reminder ;)

Comment: @craigim @erfan Don't worry, i will accept your answers and I am very grateful for your help. I just have to test the code with my data first and see if it works. Also, the file names now also contain a name, so I have to try to implement that too (`Ring6_07-06-2016_17-58-32.wf`). And unfortunately I am not that fast.